# how to addview a transparent background imageview on overlay windowmanage? android

Tags: android, overlay

every master hand person,in android,the textView can  transparent background display on the overlay windowmanage use addview.but imageView can't use.can you tell how to do  ?

use params.format=1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to theme set 
me by your problem soleva

Comment: set windowmanage parmas.format =1 .can transparent background display